# What does "of continuing scientifc utility" mean exactly?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

> Tragically, the specimens still missing as a result of the theft are vanishingly unlikely to be in a physical state, or attached to data, that would make them **of continuing scientific utility**. ([source](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/great-feather-heist-180968408/))

My understanding of the sentence is the author is saying that the specimens would not be **of continuing scientific use.** Google shows no authoritative sources for "of utility." Is this an idiomatic expression?

Comment: *Usefulness* is probably closer than *use* to the sense of utility - if only by a smidgen.

Comment: The construction ***of continuing scientific use*** doesn't sound at all good to me (does it mean *still **used by** scientists,* or *still **useful to** scientists?*). To my mind, that's the primary justification for using ***utility*** in the cited context. It's a little clumsy, but at least it's reasonably clear that these specimens wouldn't be much ***use / benefit***, even if scientists did ***use / work with*** them (which they probably don't, but that's secondary to the point being made).

Comment: I would rephrase as something like, "continue to make them useful to science," or, "continue to make them scientifically useful."  As written the sentence is grammatical but awkward.

Answer (score 1):

Utility in the context of this sentence means "capable of being used; or beneficial". So, "of continuing scientific utility' would mean 'capable of being used for scientific purposes; or beneficial for scientific investigation.' Your phrase, 'of no continuing scientific use' sums this up perfectly.

I would not call this idiomatic use as such, it is just the sort of formal language that you frequently see in scientific reports.